# Why won't the Sloan quarry workers move back into Quarry Junction?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've completed the quest where you have to kill the Deathclaw Mother and Deathclaw Alpha Male for the Sloan quarry workers. I wiped out all the deathclaws in the quarry and then notified Chomps Lewis. I've recently travelled back to talk to Melissa of the Great Khans, and noticed that the quarry is still empty. Does it take a long time for the workers to move back into the quarry, or will they never do it?

Answer (score 4):

No the workers will not return to the quarry. They will, at most, end up in a bar in bolder city.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Claws_Out